# Return object shows up in the front end but wont push to the back end

Tags: angularjs, node.js

Alright, I feel like an idiot because I've done this a thousand times... But I've been battling this for over an hour and about to head to lunch. I'm hoping someone can answer by the time I get back :)  I need to compare a password input to what I have stored in the database. When I log the object that I'm sending to the backend in the service, it shows up perfectly, but when I try to send my return object to the backend, I just get an empty object when I log "req.params". I have also tried sending it back with a "POST" instead of a "GET" and logging "req.body" but that also comes in as an empty object. Can someone please tell me what in the heck I am doing wrong? I've done it so many times and feel stupid for having to ask this question but I can't for the life of me figure it out! Thanks in advance! Here is my code

```
Controller (angular)
$scope.checkOldPassword = function(oldPassword) {
    var returnObj = {
        oldPassword: oldPassword
    }
    userSettingsService.checkPassword(returnObj).then(function(response){
        console.log(response);
    })
}

Service
this.checkPassword = function(oldPassword) {
    console.log(oldPassword);
    return $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/api/checkOldPassword',
        params: oldPassword
    }).then(function(response) {
        return response.data;
    })
};

Server.js
app.get('/api/checkOldPassword', ensureAuthenticated, UserCtrl.checkOldPassword)

UserCtrl.js (node)
checkOldPassword: function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.params);

}
```

Comment: what does "ensureAuthenticated" run ?

Comment: @AmadouBeye It makes sure that the user has the authorization to hit that endpoint. If someone that isnt logged in (or someone that is logged in, but does have the right privileges) tries to hit the endpoint, they wont get anything from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using Express, `req.params` is an object containing properties mapped to the named route “parameters”. For example, if you have the route /user/:name, then the “name” property is available as req.params.name. (see http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.params) In your case you are not calling such an URL.

I believe you have (at least) 2 options:

**Option 1:**
you might have to change your `$http` call replacing 'params' by 'data' (I don't know Angular but [this doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) seems to mention `.data` and not `.params`; in any case the Express route needs to change)

```
return $http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/api/checkOldPassword',
    data: {password: oldPassword}
}).then(function(response) {
    return response.data;
})
```

and then use `req.body` instead of `req.params` in `UserCtrl.js`

```
Server.js
app.post('/api/checkOldPassword', ensureAuthenticated, UserCtrl.checkOldPassword)

UserCtrl.js (node)
checkOldPassword: function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.body.password);
}
```

**Option 2:**
you stick to `req.params` and then adapt the URL you are calling (but the password is going to be send with the URL, it's not very safe)

```
return $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/api/checkOldPassword/'+oldPassword
}).then(function(response) {
    return response.data;
})
```

And then your route should be

```
Server.js
app.get('/api/checkOldPassword/:password', ensureAuthenticated, UserCtrl.checkOldPassword)

UserCtrl.js (node)
checkOldPassword: function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.params.password);
}
```

PS: as to your comment below, whichever option you choose, the method from your Angular `$http` call and that of the Express route `app.xxx` should match

Comment: Unfortunately, I've tried both of those options :/  Thanks though! 

Comment: what is the request that you are currently sending to your back?

Comment: Dude... I'm an idiot. Last time I tried changing the method to a "POST" instead of a "GET", I only changed it in the service and not the server.js  . Thanks!

Comment: I still dont understand why the get request wont work though... Super confused. But oh well. I'm glad this is behind me!

Comment: In Express you can find the GET request parameters in `req.query` not `req.body` nor `req.params`. Previous versions of Express used to have a method to retrieve a parameter wherever it was (`req.param()`) but it was removed from the most recent versions

Comment: Once again... You're right! req.query is what works haha. Thanks again! You're the man! 

Comment: @joshbang You're welcome  I edited my initial answer to reflect your comment so that whomever finds this post one day will get the proper answer

Answer (score 0):

Try to add header when sedding form from your service

```
headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' };
this.checkPassword = function(oldPassword) {
    console.log(oldPassword);
    return $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/api/checkOldPassword',
        params: oldPassword,
        headers: headers
    }).then(function(response) {
        return response.data;
    })
};
```

Comment: Headers went through fine, but params still wont.